# How does parsing work or what makes a type complete or incomplete?

Tags: c++

Consider the following:

```
template <typename Alg> class AlgorithmTraits;

template <class Alg>
struct Heuristic {
    using Neighbor = typename AlgorithmTraits<Alg>::Generator::Neighbor;
};

template <class Alg, template <class> class HType>
struct Generator {
    using Neighbor = int;
    HType<Alg> h_;
};
template <class Alg>
using GeneratorPolicy = Generator<Alg, Heuristic>;

template <template <class> class InitialHeuristic_,
          template <class> class Generator_> class Astar;

template <template <class> class InitialHeuristic_,
          template <class> class Generator_>
struct AlgorithmTraits<Astar<InitialHeuristic_, Generator_>> {
    using MyAlgorithm = Astar<InitialHeuristic_, Generator_>;
    using InitialHeuristic = InitialHeuristic_<MyAlgorithm>;
    using Generator = Generator_<MyAlgorithm>;
};

template <template <class> class InitialHeuristic_,
          template <class> class Generator_>
class Astar {
    using InitialHeuristic = typename AlgorithmTraits<Astar>::InitialHeuristic;
    using Generator = typename AlgorithmTraits<Astar>::Generator;
    //InitialHeuristic h_; // version 1 (does not compile)
    Generator g_;          // version 2 (compiles)
};

int main() {
    Astar<Heuristic, GeneratorPolicy> a; (void)a;
    return 0;
}
```

Please look at the line in the definition of the `Astar` class denoted as "version 2" by the comment. When `Astar` is instantiated as in `main`, the member `g_` is of type `GeneratorPolicy<Astar>`, which has a member `h_` of type which is an instantiation of `Heuristic`. However, it seems that the declaration of the `Neighbor` alias in `Heuristic` should require that `GeneratorPolicy<Astar>` be complete. I would think that it is not complete, since the compiler is in the middle of parsing it right now. Hence, I am confused as to why the code compiles.

P.S. If you answer that `GeneratorPolicy<Astar>` is complete, then please explain how come version 1 does not compile. The error output of `g++ 5.4.0` for that version is:

```
temp.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Generator<Astar<Heuristic, GeneratorPolicy>, Heuristic>’:
temp.cpp:17:72:   required from ‘struct Heuristic<Astar<Heuristic, GeneratorPolicy> >’
temp.cpp:43:22:   required from ‘class Astar<Heuristic, GeneratorPolicy>’
temp.cpp:48:39:   required from here
temp.cpp:23:16: error: ‘Generator<Alg, HType>::h_’ has incomplete type
     HType<Alg> h_;
                ^
temp.cpp:16:8: note: declaration of ‘struct Heuristic<Astar<Heuristic, GeneratorPolicy> >’
 struct Heuristic {
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to Amadeus, here is a simpler version:

```
template <typename Alg>
struct Generator;

template <typename Alg> struct Heuristic {
    using Neighbor = typename Generator<Alg>::Neighbor;
};

template <typename Alg> struct Generator {
    using Neighbor = int;
    Heuristic<Alg> h;
};

int main()
{
    Heuristic<int> x;    // Version 1 - compile error
    //Generator<int> x;  // Version 2 - compile fine
    (void)x;
}
```

However, I still do not understand clearly why Version 2 compiles fine.

Comment: Your code is very complex and thus hard to read and grasp. Try to reproduce your problem with a simpler example

Comment: An "incomplete type" is usually a type such as a `class` or `struct` that has only a declaration and no definition, something like `class Incomplete;`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very hard to understand. So, I've made a simpler version of it:

```
template <typename T>
struct Bar;

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    using a = typename Bar<T>::Type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar
{
    using Type = int;
    Foo<T> x;
};

int main()
{
    //Foo<int> x;    // Version 1 - compile error
    Bar<int> x;  // Version 2 - compile fine
    (void)x;
}
```

Well incomplete type occurs when you want to use a type before it is completed defined. In version 1, you are trying to define `Foo<int>` at same time want to use it in `Bar<int>`

In the case of version 2. You are defining `Bar<int>`, and then, defining `Foo<int>` that is using only `Bar<int>::Type`, which is easy to complete the definition.

Comment: Your simpler version captures the issue nicely. I did not understand the last few words of your answer though: "which is easy to complete the definition". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm not an expert on parsing. but I would say that in second version, `Bar<int>` is not redifining itself when instancing `Foo<int>`, but only using an alias (`Bar<int>::Type`)

Comment: I would really like to know the precise reason to avoid this kind of problems at the design stage in the future. Anyone?